# How can I convert Identity user to Claims Principal User?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I want use  User.IsInRole() function in my api controller.
I have Identity user ,how could I convert it to ClaimsPrincipal or use User.IsInRole() with Identity user ?!?!?!

Comment: [This page of Microsoft explains it very well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api#authorization-inside-a-controller-action)

Comment: In `User.IsInRole()` the `User` object is already the `ClaimsPrincipal` of the current user.

Comment: I know it, but in api controller I didn't login with any user so "User" has no related information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SignInManager<TUser>.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(TUser)` method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.createuserprincipalasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0